# SwiftUI - Deleting items from a filtered list

Tags: swiftui

I have a filtered list which I need to delete items from using the .onDelete method of ForEach. As the delete(at offsets: IndexSet) function uses the index of the currently displayed list, I need to refer to exactly this order of list items.

Unfortunately I get the following error when I want to refer to the refer to the filteredTools variable:

Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'filteredTools' is a get-only property

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

```
struct ToolList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @State var showingFilter = false
    @State var editMode = EditMode.inactive

    var toolCategories: [String: [Tool]] {
        Dictionary(
            grouping: userData.tools,
            by: { $0.category }
        )
    }

    var filteredTools: [Tool] {
        var list = [Tool]()
        for category in self.userData.selectedToolCategories {
            if category.isSelected && self.toolCategories[category.name] != nil {
                list += self.userData.showFavoritesOnly ? self.toolCategories[category.name]!.filter { $0.isFavorite } : self.toolCategories[category.name]!
            }
        }
        return list
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(filteredTools) { tool in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ToolDetail(tool: tool).environmentObject(self.userData)) {
                        ToolRow(tool: tool)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(NSLocalizedString("Tools", comment: "")))
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: EditButton(),
                trailing: NavigationBar(showingFilter: self.$showingFilter, editMode: self.$editMode)
                    .environmentObject(userData)
            )
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
            .sheet(isPresented: $userData.showingProfile) {
                ProfileHost()
                    .environmentObject(self.userData)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingFilter) {
                FilterView(isPresented: self.$showingFilter, categories: self.$userData.selectedToolCategories)
            }
        }
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        self.filteredTools.remove(atOffsets: offsets) // <-- this is where I get this error message: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'filteredTools' is a get-only property
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making `filteredTools` @State (or even use @ObservedObject). At present it is a property of a struct and thus immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by implementing the delete function back in the model instead of in the view, passing the actually displayed (filtered) List to determine the id of the item to be deleted along with the index of the item:

```
private func onDelete(offsets: IndexSet) {
    userData.delete(from: filteredTools, offsets: offsets)
}
```